# The viewport meta tag does so much more (if it comes to jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, viewport

I made a very interesting discovery today. I wrote a simple quiz browser game in jQuery in which you have to select correct answers. When you click them, the content changes by mouse click (or finger touch). This is done using

```
$("#field"+i).click(clickField);
```

where `clickField` is a JS method which deals with the click. The CSS is designed in such a way that the game is playable on Deskop and mobile screens as well. I extended the game  during the last days a lot and suddenly I realized an immense performance drop on the mobile version (on Desktop it was fast as usual even though the code doesn't make any case distinction on the device). After touching the answer buttons you could really feel that it takes the system some time to react.

Fortunately, I was using a version control system and could compare the current version to an older one which was still very fast. Step by step I threw the new features out to undestand which new feature is slowing the system down. In the end no feature was the reason but it was this simple line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
```

During the last days I removed the viewport line because my CSS was build up in such a way that I use relative width (namely `vh`and `vw`) where the viewport line shouldn't change the design.

But strangely it has a big impact on the performance. My only explanation is that the jQuery library checks for the existence of this line and in case it finds it it uses a different way to perform the jQuery action which works faster on mobile devices. Is this true? I couldn't find anything in this directing by googling.